# How to stub all methods of a class with Jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, sinon

I'm trying to reframe myself to use Jest and I'm finding it somewhat difficult migrating from sinon to it.

With sinonjs, if I had a class I could just do `sinon.createStubInstance` and sinon would give me a stubbed instance of that class, which was an object instance where all methods were stubs.

With jest, after searching the web many times, it seems that I either need to use the `__mocks__` folder abstraction and retype the whole class, or individually stub the methods.

Is there a better way? Does Jest have any method similar to `createStubInstance` from sinon?

Comment: there are 4 ways available: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks

Comment: @skyboyer These "4 methods" are really one method of calling `jest.mock('./some-module');` An entire module is not the same as a class in JS. For plenty of reasons.

Comment: @Gherman so you say you have some module and want/need to mock only one class from that module but don't want to mock another class from the same module that may refer to methods of class1 under mock. Did I get it right?

Comment: @skyboyer yes. I am trying to mock EntityManager and/or Connection from TypeORM. I might break TypeORM if I mock all of it. I made another question about it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61637468/how-to-stub-entitymanager-and-connection-in-typeorm-with-jest