# Connection "default" was not found with NestJS Unit Testing of Service

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocking, nestjs, typeorm

I am currently unit testing my NestJS service. My entity is called 'User' and I established a basic Service that allows me to interact with a MS SQL server, with GET and POST endpoints established in my Controller.

While I was able to mock the `Repository` that is used in the Service, I was unable to establish a mock `getConnection` in a method that had to call `getConection()`.

When I tried unit testing with `npm run test:watch`, I get the error that `ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found.` I have looked into (and in fact, taken much from) [How to stub EntityManager and Connection in TypeORM with Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61637468/how-to-stub-entitymanager-and-connection-in-typeorm-with-jest), but this post does not seem to elaborate on a connection that was not established, which is my problem.

In any case, here's my service with the relevant parts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { getConnection, Repository } from "typeorm";
import {User} from '../entities/user.entity';


@Injectable()
export class ServiceName {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(User) private usersRepository: Repository<User>) {}

  // Creating and inserting a new user into the database table using Repository
  // unit testing for this one works fine
  async createUserRepository(user: User): Promise<User> {
    const newUser = this.usersRepository.create(user); 
    return await this.usersRepository.save(newUser);
  }

  // Creating and inserting a new user into the database table using QueryBuilder and getConnection
  // unit testing for this one does not work so well 
  async createUserQueryBuilder(user: User): Promise<User> {
    await getConnection()
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .insert()
    .into(User)
    .values([
        user, 
     ])
    .execute();
    return user;  
  }
```

And here's my spec.ts file for unit testing:

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { ServiceName } from './app_codes_rms_area.service';
import { getRepositoryToken } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { User } from '../entities/user.entity';
import { Connection, Repository } from 'typeorm';

describe('service tests', () => {

    const repositoryMockFactory: () => MockType<Repository<any>> = jest.fn(() => ({ 
        create: jest.fn(),
        save: jest.fn(),
        // other functions
    }));

    const mockConnectionFactory = jest.fn(() => ({
        getConnection: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
            createQueryBuilder: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
            getMany: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(allUsers),
            insert: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
            into: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
            values: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
            execute: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(user),
        })
    }));
 
    let service: ServiceName;
    let mockRepository: MockType<Repository<User>>;
    let mockConnection: Connection;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [
                ServiceName,
                {
                    provide: getRepositoryToken(User), // a User Repository is injected to the service 
                    useFactory: repositoryMockFactory, // using factory ensures that a new mock is used for every test
                },
                {
                    provide: Connection,
                    useFactory: mockConnectionFactory,
                }
            ],
        }).compile();

        service = module.get<ServiceName>(ServiceName);
        mockRepository = module.get(getRepositoryToken(User));
        mockConnection = module.get<Connection>(Connection);
    });
        it('should create a new user and return it using Repository', async () => {
            // some test that passes using mockRepository
        });

        it('should create a new user and return it using QueryBuilder (with mocked Connection)', async () => {
            expect(await service.createUserQueryBuilder(user)).toEqual(user);
            expect(mockConnection.createQueryBuilder).toBeCalled();
            expect(mockConnection.createQueryBuilder()['insert']).toBeCalled();
            expect(mockConnection.createQueryBuilder()['into']).toBeCalled();
            expect(mockConnection.createQueryBuilder()['values']).toBeCalled();
            expect(mockConnection.createQueryBuilder()['execute']).toBeCalled();
        })
```

It is the second test, `it('should create a new user and return it using QueryBuilder (with mocked Connection)'`, that triggers the following error:

```
  ● service tests › Service Functions › should create a new user and return it using QueryBuilder (with mocked Connection)

    ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found.

      at new ConnectionNotFoundError (error/ConnectionNotFoundError.ts:8:9)
      at ConnectionManager.Object.<anonymous>.ConnectionManager.get (connection/ConnectionManager.ts:40:19)
      at Object.getConnection (index.ts:252:35)
      at ServiceName.createUserQueryBuilder (somefile:19:11)
      at Object.it (somefile:134:34)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to change your `createUserQueryBuilder` method like below:

```js
async createUserQueryBuilder(user: User): Promise<User> {
  await this.usersRepository
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .insert()
    .into(User)
    .values([
        user, 
     ])
    .execute();
  return user;  
}
```

Then you can update the repository mock `repositoryMockFactory`:

```js
const repositoryMockFactory: () => MockType<Repository<any>> = jest.fn(() => ({ 
  create: jest.fn(),
  save: jest.fn(),
  createQueryBuilder: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  getMany: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(allUsers),
  insert: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  into: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  values: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  execute: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(user),
}));
```

### Update:

Based on your request, you can do something like this as well.

Update your `spec.ts` file,

```js
import * as typeorm from 'typeorm';

const getConnectionSpy = jest.spyOn(typeorm, 'getConnection');
getConnectionSpy.mockImplementation(() => ({
  createQueryBuilder: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  getMany: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(allUsers),
  insert: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  into: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  values: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  execute: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(user),
}));
```

Note that you will have to update your other `typeorm` imports accordingly.
e.g.: `typeorm.Connection`

This is just for you to get an idea on how to do it. There might be syntax errors since I didn't test this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Indeed, this seems to work; but I would really like to stick to using `getConnection()`. (Really, it is for practice; my new role involves NestJS). Do you have any suggestions for mocking getConnection? I've found a way where I use `@InjectConnection() private connection: Connection` in my service and combine it with `{provide: Connection, useFactory: mockConnectionFactory, }` in my spec.ts file (and it works), but here I'm mocking an injected connection, NOT the getConnection that is imported. It'd be really nice if I could mock the imported getConnection.

Comment: I updated my answer though I can not guarantee that it would work. Good luck with your new role! 

Comment: Uhmm, still not; but thanks for the answer! I feel like I have some tweaking to do here and there, perhaps...

Comment: Edit: I adapted your approach to a simpler example where I'm using `getManager()` followed by `delete` a single function and it worked! I'm pretty sure that some further tweaking is necessary to make the chain of functions in `createQueryBuilder` to work (it's probably much more complicated...). Thanks again!

Comment: Wow, great. Glad I could help 